# How do I ask a question about literature that I don't know exists, but which the people answering it do, without the question being "open ended"?

Tags: discussion

I've had a number of occasions when I've tried asking questions relating to books or other pieces of literature that fall into an extremely niche genre, but which I cannot name individually because I haven't yet discovered them yet, but the questions have been deleted as being "open ended".

Is there any way to ask a question about literature that I don't know about without it being considered open ended?

For example, if I'm trying to find information about how a specific genre has evolved over time, including books that I haven't heard of, but which the person answering the question might have?

Comment: Your [most recent question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19910/17) hasn't been closed or deleted, so you successfully moulded that into a non-open-ended form, but I don't know if it really gave you what you wanted to know?

Comment: I'd also point again to [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5388/17) for a good example of a well-received question about how a specific genre has evolved over time. If I can summarise nicely the aspects of that question that made it "better" (by site scope standards) than yours, I'll post an answer to this meta. For now, +1 to you for raising a constructive meta post for feedback.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor The only way that I could get the question to stick was by making it completely useless for my purpose.

Comment: Understood, so the second question isn't useful for you, you want to ask something more like the first one but in a way that's on-topic here. (Maybe edit links to both questions into this meta, for a clearer discussion?)

Comment: I still fail to see why my question was considered open ended, and why that question wasn't deleted for soliciting opinions, when some of mine have.

Comment: Your guidance is unclear. Please provide specific examples of good practice.

Comment: I used your example and my question was deleted.

Comment: No, you don't have any deleted questions on this site. You might be thinking of a question you asked on a different site, which isn't something you can get help with on this meta. Different SE sites have different scopes, communities, policies, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131543/discussion-between-aaargh-zombies-and-rand-althor).